# Calling a mysql stored procedure in groovy

Tags: mysql, groovy

So I'm trying the execute the following stored procedure in groovy

```
str = 'call proc("config", "insert into table (name, val) VALUES (?, ?)"'
sql.call(str, ['name', 'val'])
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of 
parameters, which is 0).
```

My guess is that because the question marks in inside a secondary set of quotation marks it doesn't find them as parameters.

I tried using named parameters as well `?.name` or `:name`
but nothing worked.

Any ideas of to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure query is OK, has "indirection" or "inclusion" maybe illegal ... so mayby error isn't groovy related

Comment: The same query (with values obviously) works when I execute it directly on the database

Comment: have you tried like this? `'{call....}'`

Comment: Using `{ }` Gives me a `java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Comment: 1) as for me the `)` is missing to close proc parameters- if yes please modify the question... 2) can you provide the working query with obviously defined values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) strings in mysql could be doublequoted.

so actually you are calling procedure with 2 string parameters

```
call proc("string1", "whatever ? ?")
```

mysql after parsing this query will return 0 input parameters because you specified two parameters of your stored procedure explicitly.

so you have an error `Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).` when passing 2 parameters for this query when database don't see them.

you can do something like this:

```
def parm2 = "insert into table (name, val) VALUES ('$name', '$value')"
str = 'call proc("config", ? )'
sql.call(str, [parm2])
```

of cause you have to manage `'` escaping in your `name` and `value` strings.

and potentially it's a code with [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security issue.

better to re-think your database procedure parameters to avoid passing sql query as a parameter.

Comment: We've decided to indeed do something else instead of using this procedure in the end